# Hide part of HTML page from Google

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-search, googlebot

I have a simple HTML page and I need to hide a little part of the text from Google.

`<p> text i want to hide </p>`

I could load this text with php include and use a robots.txt but the problem is - if someone would set a link to this php file - Google would again show the text I want to hide.

My next idea was:

```
$str = 'textiwanttohide';
echo base64_decode($str);
```

but the problem is - Google encodes this within seconds and the text is shown in the Google results.

So how can I hide a specific part of my text from Google? Is there a php or javascript solution?

Comment: "i could load this text with php include and use a robots.txt " nope that would not work

Comment: Why not just set a META description? That will be what is displayed in the search results vs text from your site content.

Comment: How about converting the text into a CAPTCHA? this way, not just google but any other search engines will not expose the text: http://fakecaptcha.com/

Comment: captchas woul be a good solution - the problem is : i cant use images (its a little hard to explain) - i need a simple "text" solution ... html,php,javascript

Comment: META description does not solve the problem ... because you could still google the text i want to hide ... i want to hide this part of the text so that you cant find it with google

Answer (score 3):

the proper way is:

```
indexed
<!--googleoff: all--> not indexed <!--googleon: all>
```

See [Excluding Unwanted Text from the Index](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/preparing.html#1076243) for details.

Comment: .. my extensive 3 minutes of research indicates this will not work (sorry about that) :( but thanks for the upvote points  :-)

Comment: Welcome. Nonetheless, it could still prove useful, yes?

Comment: every thing has its uses :-)

Comment: True. OP could use a text to image code from `ImageCreate`. Similar to what I use for anti-botting. Not a CAPTCHA though, as suggested under OP's question, that'd be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the text in a database like MySQL and load it dynamically with jquery and Ajax. So I think Google shouldn't find this text.